# Bash pipestatus value lost when returning value from a function

Tags: linux, bash, return, return-value

cat velero-credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = pHYxIoNAlYSitERdaToREwStaLiShaNEraPTISCrOLOwlIQuanSENtAlF
aws_secret_access_key = NsMatEbirYSIaVerIacisHatERtorYouSISTerNeAShRoplEgRAhAZERm
```

The code that has issues looks as follows:

```
get_credentials_head () {
  cat < "$VELERO_CREDENTIALS" | head -1 | grep '\[default\]' > /dev/null 2>&1
  declare -r status=${PIPESTATUS[2]}
  echo $status
  return $status
}

get_aws_access_key_id () {
  cat < "$VELERO_CREDENTIALS" | grep 'aws_access_key_id' | grep '^aws_access_key_id = .*' > /dev/null 2>&1
  declare -r status=${PIPESTATUS[2]}
  echo $status
  return $status
}

get_aws_secret_access_key () {
  cat < "$VELERO_CREDENTIALS" | grep 'aws_secret_access_key' | grep '^aws_access_key_id = .*' > /dev/null 2>&1
  declare -r status=${PIPESTATUS[2]}
  echo $status
  return $status
}

if [ -z "$DATACENTRE" ]; then
  echo "Please specify a datacentre, exiting without running!"
  exit 1
fi

# Probably a cleaner way to handle this in bash.
if [ "$RESTORE" ]; then
  if [ -f "$VELERO_CREDENTIALS" ];then
    declare get_credentials_head_value=$(get_credentials_head)
    if [ ! "${get_credentials_head_value}" ];then
      echo "please set your aws_access_key_id"
      exit 1
    fi

    declare get_aws_access_key_id_value=$(get_aws_access_key_id)
    if [ ! "${get_aws_access_key_id_value}" ];then
      echo "please set your aws_access_key_id"
      exit 1
    fi

    declare get_aws_secret_access_key_value=$(get_aws_secret_access_key)
    if [ ! "${get_aws_secret_access_key_value}" ];then
      echo "please set your aws_access_key_id"
      exit 1
    fi
  else
    echo "Restore option specified but file: $VELERO_CREDENTIALS does not exist"
    exit 1
  fi
fi
}
```

The issue I have is around the functions that get pipe status, it seems the pipestatus integer is ephemeral. I have tried returning the pipestatus directly out of the function and it has no value outside.

I have have opted for setting a status variable using declare -r, In the hope that the variable can not then lose its value.

It's rather strange.

I would look to remove those echo $status lines once its working as expected.

Comment: Your pipestatus is fine. Your `if [ ! "${get_credentials_head_value}" ]` is not a correct way to test if a variable containing an integer value is non-zero. Try `if [ "${get_credentials_head_value}" -ne 0 ]`.

Comment: I think you are confusing a bit with `if ! get_credentials_head` (`then` block executes if the command failed), which you could have done as alternative to capturing the return value in a variable.  (By the way, in the interest of minimal reproducible example, you could show the call just one of these functions, rather than all three.)